# Error: Unexpected request: GET when trying to use http.get In Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am using http service to load json and bind the data to my UI. But I get the following error. I am not writing any tests FYI.

Error: Unexpected request: GET

```
 ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: Unexpected request: GET 'MYJSONURL'
No more request expected
at $httpBackend (angular-mocks.js:1406)
at sendReq (ionic.bundle.js:23645)
at serverRequest (ionic.bundle.js:23357)
at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:27879)
at ionic.bundle.js:27895
at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:29158)
at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:28969)
at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:29263)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:62385)
at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16583)
```

Here is my service.

```
app.service('AuthService', function ($q, $http) {

function getdata() {
    var dataSource = 'MYJSONURL';

    return $http.get(dataSource);

}
return {
    getdata:getdata
};
})
```

Controller

```
 app.controller('loginctrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService, AUTH_EVENTS) {
$scope.login = function (data) {
   AuthService.getdata().then(function (response) {
            _this.mydata = response.data;
        }).catch(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        });
}});
```

Comment: you should write success of your $http.get method that can be bind in your UI

Comment: I did that . But it doesn't work.  .success(function (data) {
               alert(data)
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                alert(data)
            });

Comment: The debugger is going to error function

Comment: did you check in **postman** what did you get in there

Comment: send  me you response for your json string